# Some fake data coming automatically in webserver databse

Tags: php, laravel, web

In our  Company Website  there is  a webpage contact form , in front-end it is validate by jquery validation Engine and in back-end it is validate by(used laravel framework) and also google recapture there. But Why   every day some fake data is store in our server database?(Moreover the form submit time is exactly same for three to five record and the form is submitted in Russian Language)
link: https://microtechits.com/MGITS-Contact

Comment: May be you used external service like google ...

Comment: Every day store the data at some particular time like seed in laravel

Comment: It is hard to answer to question without getting any piece of the code. I suggest 2 reasons why that happening. First, your captcha isn't working well and spammers can submit your form. Second, your Laravel developer could forget to remove faker factory. Factory can create some fake value and put it to the database (in Laravel it is calling `seeds`)

Comment: Add some tracking and logging to determine when the data is submitted, and who submitted it. Verify that your ReCAPTCHA is properly implemented (just having the box there doesn't make it implemented, you need some client/server verification).

Comment: Have you tried checking and blocking the IP Address of the Users submitting form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick workaround:
Add a validation on Laravel side (server side validation) with a regex allowing only non-russian characters.

Then

1. **Post your code** with implementation of Google reCAPTCHA, there we'll find the answer.
2. **Which version** of Google reCAPTCHA you are using..?

Comment: reCAPTCHA  version 2